# Exception Illegal value in Firebug

Tags: jquery, exception, firebug

Today, I've found exception in my firebug console:

uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal value" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" location: "JS frame :: http://portal.aolcdn.com/p5/_v39.5/js/main.js :: anonymous :: line 196" data: no]

Comment: Please could you link to the website that this problem is found on. If the JavaScript is accessed directly it's not parsed by the browser or in any way *used* (it's just presented as text), and so won't generate any error messages. Incidentally, is it **only** Firefox? What version? What platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens for example happen you pass `undefined` (instead of a string) as an URL to an `XmlHttpRequest` object. The object detects that this is an invalid value and throws an exception. The exact cause of the problem depends on the code at that position.

Inspect the values of the variables that are used there and see if any of them contain unexpected content.